# How to bundle npm packages with webpack and expose as an object?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-2

I'm not actually sure this is possible, but what I'm trying to do is take a number of NPM packages, bundle them together using Webpack and expose them as an object where each package is a property.

For example, if I wanted `react` and `react-dom` bundled, it would then provide an object like:

```
{
    'react': /* react code */,
    'react-dom': /* react-dom code */
}
```

My current configuration is:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [ 'react', 'react-dom' ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8081/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  }
};
```

This seems to somewhat work in the fact that it does return an object, but the object it returns is whatever the last `entry` package is, so in this case, the object contains all of `react-dom`'s methods.

If I were to change the order of the `entry` array to `[ 'react-dom', 'react' ]`, then only the `react` methods would be exposed.

The idea would be to export the object so I can access both package methods using their properties like `react.Component` or `react.PureComponent`

I've also tried using the `expose-loader`, but that yields the same results as above, unless I configured it incorrectly.

Any ideas on how to properly configure webpack to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you could just set up a, let's say, `bundle-source.js` with this structure:

```
exports.react = require('react');
exports['react-dom'] = require('react-dom');
exports.anyModule = require('anyModule');
```

Then you set that `bundle-source.js` as the entry point of your webpack conf:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [ '...path-to...bundle-source.js' ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8081/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  }
};
```